# Prediction of the state of a Gaussian state process

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, control-theory

Once again this engineering brain is lost due to a lot of formal mathematics.

Consider the recursion $x(t+1) = A(t)x(t) + M(t)v(t)$

where $ x(t_0)=x_0$, $T = \{t_0,t_0 + 1,\ldots\}\subset\mathbb{Z}_+$, $x_0:\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^n$, $x_0 \in G(0,Q_0)$

***EDIT: (meaning $x_0$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $Q_0$), and I assume that it should be $x_0:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}^n$, but there's an error in the exercise I guess***,

$v:\Omega \times \mathbb{R}^{m_v}$, is a Gaussian white noise process with $v(t) \in G(0,Q_v)$, $\forall t\in T$,

$\mathcal{F}^{x_0}$, $\mathcal{F}^{v}_{\infty}$ are independent $\sigma$-algebras.

$A: T\to \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, $M:T\to\mathbb{R}^{n \times m_v}$, $Q_v \in \mathbb{R}^{m_v \times m_v}$,

$Q_v = Q^T_v > 0$,

$Q_x(t) = \mathbf{E} \left[ \left(x(t) - \mathbf{E}\left[x(t)\right] \right) \left( x(t) - \mathbf{E}\left[x(t)\right] \right)^T \right] > 0 $, $\forall t \in T$, assumed.

Derive a formula for $\mathbf{E}\left[x(t+2)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right]$,$\forall t\in \mathbb{Z}_+$ in terms of $x(t)$ and deterministic functions. *Hint: use induction. This exercise needs concepts of Markov processes and of Gaussian processes.*

---

Currently I've rewritten it in the following way:
$$x(t+2) = A(t+1)\left(A(t)x(t) + M(t)v(t)\right) + M(t+1)v(t+1)$$

and I have tried different approaches, but somehow haven't figured out a way that seems to get near to the solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with the notation $G(\cdot, \cdot)$. In particular the expressions
$$x_0:\Omega\times\mathbb R^n, x_0\in G(0,Q_0) $$
are not clearly defined.

Comment: I've edited it in the proper way. Haha I already thought that it was a bit strange notation by the lecturer, because I've never seen it in other books.

Comment: Simply crank out the recursion and apply $\mathbb E$. The covariances are known.

Comment: Is it really just:

$$\mathbf{E}\left[x(t+2)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right] = \mathbf{E}\left[A(t+1)x(t+1) + M(t+1)v(t+1)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right] = \\
A(t+1)\mathbf{E}\left[x(t+1)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right] + M(t+1)\mathbf{E}\left[ v(t+1)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right]= \\
A(t+1)\mathbf{E}\left[A(t)x(t) + M(t)v(t)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right] + 0 = \\
A(t+1)\mathbf{E}\left[A(t)x(t)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right] + A(t+1)\mathbf{E}\left[M(t)v(t)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right] = \\
A(t+1)A(t) \mathbf{E}\left[x(t)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)}\right] = A(t+1)A(t)$$

Comment: Or is the last equality not true and should I continue until a certain $t_0$, where we find that $\mathbf{E}\left[x(t_0)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)} \right] = 0$? And therefore $\mathbf{E}\left[x(t+i)|\mathcal{F}^{x(t)} \right] = 0 \forall i\in T$?

Comment: I meant in my first answer $A(t+1)A(t)x(t)$? (haha sorry for the many comments, the given $x(t_0)=x_0 \in G(0,Q_0)$ has thrown me a bit off my path.